# How to consume an API given this information (PHP, Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.8

The API has an internal documentation page that asks me for Client ID, Client Secret, Username and Password.

Once I enter those, it stays "Authenticated" and I can "Try out" any request within that page.

Now the documentation for "Authenticate" is this:

```
/auth Authenticate to API
grant_type (password/refresh token)
client_id*
client_secret*
username*
password*
token (used only for refresh_token as grant type)
```

When I initiate a POST request (via cURL) I get an access_token.

From then on, what's the correct way to `GET` an `/users` endpoint for example and stay authenticated?

I'm doing this from within Laravel 5.8.

Comment: Well, the API's documentation should tell you, but a fairly conventional design is that you pass the access token in each request, generally inside an "Authorization" HTTP header which is part of the request. So in your /users GET request, you'd also set a suitable header containing the token. Again, the API docs should be telling you what to do. (If it's not documented directly in the entry for /users, there's probably a more general security / authentication article in there, because the process will likely be the same for all secured endpoints.)

Comment: The provider API is also Laravel (if that matters), sending the access token inside authorization http header I haven't tried. I'll try that. :)